# Abundant Numbers in C

Tags: c

I have a programming assignment that I'm really stumped on. The question is:

**Write a program that reads in a list of numbers, and for each number, determines and prints out whether or not that number is abundant.**

**Input Specification
1. The first integer input will be a positive integer, n, indicating the number of test cases coming next.
2. The next n inputs are single positive integers each, and for each you are to determine whether the number is abundant or not.**

**Output Specification
Output a line with one of the two the following formats for each input number:
Test case #t: X is abundant.
Test case #t: X is NOT abundant.**

Right now this is all I have written, I'm not sure how to figure out the abundant number part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){

int n, i, array [] = {n}; 

printf("Please enter n followed by n numbers:");
scanf(" %d", &n);

for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    scanf(" %d", &array[n]);
}

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, I'll bite: what's the definition of an "abundant number"?

Comment: I don't suppose the words "allocate memory" were covered in that class before this assignment was handed out?

Comment: Please look into the help text https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, to see what type of questions are welcome on SO. You don't explain your problem, you don't provide real code that has to do with abundant numbers... Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Abundant numbers is a very simple concept - you can find the information in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number

I think if you want just any solution (not the fastest) you can just explicitly find all divisors and their sum for each number.

Answer (score 0):

First of all...

```
int n, i, array [] = {n};
```

doesn't do what you think it does; it declares `array` to hold exactly 1 element, and that one element is initialized to the value of `n` (which hasn't been initialized itself, so the value will be indeterminate).  It will not be able to hold `n` values.

Based on the specification you've given, you shouldn't actually need to store the entire list of input numbers; you should be able to read one, test for abundance, then read the next, test for abundance, etc.  So the structure of your code will be something like:

```
int n = 0;
...
printf("Please enter n followed by n numbers:");
scanf(" %d", &n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
  int candidate;
  scanf( "%d", &candidate );                // read the next input

  printf( "%d is%s abundant\n", 
    candidate,
    !test( candidate ) ? " NOT" : "" );     // test the next input and
                                            // print NOT if the test fails
}
```

The `printf` statement is a compact way of writing

```
if ( test( candidate ) == 0 )
  printf( "%d is NOT abundant\n", candidate );
else
  printf( "%d is abundan\n", candidate );
```

The `test` function is something you're going to need to figure out for yourself, but the outline of it will be

1. Find the proper divisors of the input value
2. Sum them together
3. Compare that result to the input
4. Return 1 is the result is greater than the input, 0 otherwise.